# My anthurium's leaves are turning yellow and brown

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, container-gardening

I recently got this anthurium from Safeway. I put it away in my room from a south facing window. And then repotted it into a bigger pot with regular potting mix. The plants leaves started to get brown tips. So I put into another room which gets less light. But the leaves are still getting brown and new leaves dying.

- Should I water it throughly only when it gets dry. The soil did not feel dry till about a week. Should I wait till it gets dry or water every other day.
- I did try to spray a little water on it every once in a while.
- I read that anthurium prefer overcrowded roots but I repotted into a bigger pot, should I repot into a smaller pot.
  More images on google drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3wEFDNIV6IFNHZfU3YxRThFbmM

[image]

Comment: Are you using tap water or well water to water this plant?

Comment: tap water. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Likely this is a problem with watering and humidity, about which this plant is fussy, rather than the fact you repotted. Anthuriums require high humidity and they do not like to dry out, so, unlike most plants, these should be given a little water every few days to keep the compost moist at all times - but don't leave it standing in water. To try to increase humidity around the plant, you can use a pebble tray - a tray that's twice as wide as the pot, full with pebbles and which you keep half full with water, and stand the plant on top of the pebbles (not sitting in the water though). The idea is the water in the tray creates a humid micro climate around the plant. Mist the leaves frequently with water.

Bright daylight in winter, and protect from summer sun are the other recommendations, along with average warmth - minimum 60degF in winter.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above mentioned, please check for pests like white flies and fungus gnats.  My indoor anthuriums first shown the yellow leaves as pictured during winter because over watering that also led to fungus gnats issues.  As the weather turned warmer from end of spring going into summer hot weather, I suddenly found many tiny white crawlers on the anthuriums and around the pot.  Only just managed the pest control with a heavy hair cut and reporting.  Good luck with yours